# Device SNMP Commands

Tags: snmp

As I have read, there are various SNMP commands such as SNMPGET and SNMPSET etc.

> The SNMPGET command is of the form [Acc] [-n] [-b] Recno|Name
>   Variable1 [Variable2 …].
>
> This command performs an SNMP *Get* or *GetNext* operation with one or
>   more variables.  The output is the result of the operation, with each
>   returned variable and value on a separate line in the form
>   *NodeName:Variable=Value*.

The description of this command explains what the parameters of the command are:

> 1. *Acc* - SNMPc server Access Parameter.
> 2. *-n*  - Use SNMP *GetNext* operation3.
> 3. *-b*  - Bare mode; display value ony.
> 4. *Recno|Name* - Record number or name of a map object.
> 5. *VariableN*  - SNMP variable name(s).

I understand that [*Acc*], [*-n*], and [*-b*] are optional, but if I do have to use them, I am confused about what they exactly mean or look like. If anyone knows about this or could give me an exact example of what this command looks like and where to find these parameters, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the `Device SNMP Commands` from `SNMPc 7.1  Custom Service Polling Custom Scripting Support` from 
`Castle Rock Computing`. Its manual is available [here](http://snmp.co.uk/snmpc/pdf/snmpc71.doc)

If you don't have that particular tool kit there are many alternate options that interact using the SNMP protocol e.g. [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/).